# Javascript export in JSON and download it as text file by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, json, button, download, export

I am working with javascript + Raphael.js and would like to export the paper with JSON and download it as a text file by clicking a button.

I have already managed to export the paper with JSON due to **raphael.json.js** and save it as a string:

```
var json = paper.toJSON();
```

and I have also found something to download it as a text file:

```
var a = document.body.appendChild(
            document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.txt";
    a.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(json);
    a.innerHTML = "download example text";
```

but unfortunately only by creating a link instead of clicking a button and I have no idea how to manage that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: somebody answered here: [Javascript set file in download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376161/javascript-set-file-in-download)

Comment: This library is really good at doing that: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/. I've been using it for a while