# Is it possible to get D3js charts into xml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have created a simple Area chart from D3js Example. Now i want to export complete code of area chart into xml so that any end user can manually change xml data and then save it and use it. 
Is there a way to achieve in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are generating SVG via D3.js, it is naturally XML - which is handy for you.

You could grab the SVG from the HTML DOM and use the FileSaver API to generate a file to save.

Here is a [FileSaver polyfil which also has a nice introduction](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

Alternatively you could send the SVG (from the DOM) via Ajax and do it server-side.

UPDATE:

Here is an example of grabbing the svg element on the client side, however it generates the download vis the server-side. Mixed with FileSaver you could do the lot client side.
http://d3export.housegordon.org/

Comment: Thanks @Alex Key for your answer is there any simple example so that i can refer it.

Comment: No worries @Mayur I've added an example of the client-side, but I've not come across (yet) a complete client side example.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) I don't think you can export the chart but you can try exporting the chart data.