# Use window.open without resetting hash?

Tags: javascript

I have a window with a hash parameter set.

If I then do `window.open` (I want to allow the user to [download some data as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)), it resets the hash in the current window:

```
window.location.hash = 'helloworld';
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,id,name\n3,james')";
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
$('#data-link').on('click', function() {
  window.open(encodedUri);
});
```

How can I use `window.open` without resetting the hash?

It's a bit hard to demo this in jsfiddle, but hopefully the above code shows the problem.

Comment: Why the close vote? How is this not about programming in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the url is changing, than you are using a link or a button which is navigating the page. Cancel the click action so the page does not redirect.

```
$('#data-link').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.open(encodedUri);
});
```