# Export data to a excel file with JavaScript? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, handsontable

I have a collection of data that I process with jQuery. I managed that to representate it on the browser using the [Handsontable component](http://handsontable.com/). It works great, but I want to export that data into a excel file to use it offline. How can I do it using JavaScript? Is there another (better) option?

Regards!

Comment: Use CSV, easier, can be opened and viewed well with excel. 
see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: Yes, I know that CSV is easier, but I want to know if it is possible to do it directly on xls.