# export to csv (JavaScript, ClientSide)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen this [how to export javascript array info to csv on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

which works fine for me but there's a thing that annoys me.
in CSV you can seperate the strings in differents cell with a simple comma (,) so you got like:

```
[["name1", "city_name1", ...], ["name2", "city_name2", ...]]
```

and name1 and city_name1 are in the same cell. Is there a way to get them in two different cells in Excel with JavaScript?

Comment: The snippet you have there is an array of arrays. Is the entire array entered into a single cell, or is the outer array being split up while the inner arrays are being kept together?

Comment: name1 city_name1 and so on are in one cell in the first row and name2 and city_name2 are in the second row also in one cell

Comment: I'm confused. What I see in your example is an array of rows, not cells. name1 is in row 1 column 1 and city_name1 is in row 1 column 2. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to put name1 in the first row, first cell, city_name1 in the first row cell2 and name2 second row, first cell and so on

Comment: That still does not make any sense. When you parse a CSV it comes out as an array of arrays. Array[0] is a row Array[0][0] is a cell. Unless you have a field in quotes like "name1, city_name1" and you need to manually parse it, or you want to flatten the array, then you already have what you are asking for.

Comment: ooh now i got, sorry, it's my first time parsing into CSV. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I will edit my answer. Please accept thereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse a CSV in JavaScript, the array of arrays that results is not an array of cells. It is an array of rows where Array[0] is a row and Array[0][0] is a cell. What you have here is exactly what you are already asking for- name1 in row 1 cell 1, and name2 in row 2 cell 1.

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly you are asking for, but this is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set your data up in a hidden html table? The table will pop into the csv complete with your css styles. So if you want name1 and city_name1 in cells 1 and 2 of row 1, and then name2 and city_name2 in cells 1 and 2 of row 2, set the table up like that.