# Export to table values to csv

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am generating a table of clicks' coordinates **[here](http://hockeybank.nl/mapping/balbezit.html)**. Try clicking somewhere on the field, you'll understand.

Now, I want to export this table as CSV file. I need to make it work with iPad or Tablet.

Hopefully you guys can help me!

Comment: Hopefully, you know that you have tens of errors in your console (there is no element with id `status`).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Convert your table contents to CSV text:

   ```
   var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#table tr');
   var csvText = [].map.call(rows, function(row) {
       return [].map.call(row.children, function(cell) { return cell.innerText; }).join(';');
   }).join('\n');
   ```
2. Create a `Blob` from this CSV

   ```
   var blob = new Blob([csvText], { type: 'text/csv' });
   ```
3. Download this `Blob`:

   ```
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.download = 'export.csv';
   a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   a.click();
   ```

`Blob` constructing is supported by all modern browsers, but you may want to check [this compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder).