# How to export the angular generated table from database to the csv format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**index.html** 
http://pastie.org/10777655

**app.js**
http://pastie.org/10777651

I am new to angularjs. Can anybody please solve this problem? Please reload the pastie url if it does not works.

Comment: You don't need any Angular skill to generate CSV file. Basically your content is in the form of array. Look here for your solution. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side**

Comment: I need to solve it using angular. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking after ngCsv documentation found errors in your application.

1) ngCsv module has dependency of ngSanitize which you not included.

2) **ng-csv="getArray()"** Could be an expression, a value or a promise. But in your case i think something wrong.

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp',['ngSanitize','ngCsv']);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){

var endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080';

$scope.show_table = true;

$scope.ShowSearchTab= true;

$scope.hideTable = function(){
    $scope.show_table = false;
};

$scope.ClickShow = function(){
    $scope.ShowSearchTab = true;
};

$scope.test = [
                {'companyname':'Company 1', 'streetaddress':'Address 1', 'executive':'exe 1', 'webaddress':'www.example1.com', 'dunsno':'xxx', 'leadid':'yyy'},
                {'companyname':'Company 2', 'streetaddress':'Address 2', 'executive':'exe 2', 'webaddress':'www.example2.com', 'dunsno':'xxx', 'leadid':'yyy'},
                {'companyname':'Company 3', 'streetaddress':'Address 3', 'executive':'exe 3', 'webaddress':'www.example3.com', 'dunsno':'xxx', 'leadid':'yyy'},
                {'companyname':'Company 4', 'streetaddress':'Address 4', 'executive':'exe 4', 'webaddress':'www.example4.com', 'dunsno':'xxx', 'leadid':'yyy'}
           ]
  $scope.getArray = function(){
    return $scope.test;
  }

});
```

Working Plunkr is here https://plnkr.co/edit/K5l3snujJ3GQtPyjRJLZ?p=preview

Comment: If I need s.n column which will go from 1 to n. How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get at all. Can u explain what you want exactly?

Comment: I mean to say the row number should be generated like 1 to n according to the table's row.

Comment: I mean to say the row number should be generated like 1 to n according to the table's row in the Serial Number (S.N) column.

Comment: Updated Plunkr. If you have multiple records not to do this is my suggestion. And accept answer if your problem is solved.