# Download form values as csv on click using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a small app and I need to enter information using dropdown menus to then download the values as a csv file to be manipulated in Python. It's all offline; the only reason why I am using Javascript is because I need to show interactive svg charts and its easier in a browser. My form is something like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <select name="dropdownMenu">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
  </select><br>
</form>
```

And then I know I can access the selected form value with something like:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="alert(document.myForm.dropdownMenu.value)">
```

Is there any way to trigger a `download` of that value with something like this?:

```
<a href="document.myForm.dropdownMenu.value" download="myFile.csv">Download</a>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the encodeURI and window.open functions

```
   var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvjson);
   window.open(encodedUri);
   var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a complete answer, but merely a collection of ideas:

- Add an id to your link `<a id="somethingUnique" href=...` so that you can retrieve it later
- Create a function that changes the *href* attribute (`var link = document.getElementById("somethingUnique"); link.setAttribute("href", document.myForm.dropdownMenu.value);`)
- Call this function on the select `change` event ([see here how to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change))

Then when the link is clicked, the correct hyperlink is used.