# Iron-ajax download file

Tags: ajax, download, polymer

I want to using download a file using Polymer's Iron-Ajax.

```
<iron-ajax
  id="fileDownloader"
  headers='{"Auth" :"token"}'
  url="/my/server/rest/download/csv/{{id}}"
  method="GET"
  content-type="application/json"
  on-response="downloadCsvCallLoaded"
  on-error="downloadCsvCallFailed">
</iron-ajax>
```

The reposnse actually contains the data, but it does not trigger the browser to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `handle-as="blob"`property in your element declaration.
[Here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-handleAs) you can find more information about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still does not trigger the download of the data in the response as a file.

Comment: Why to use ajax for download a file? Why not use a simple new tab using the url that you give in your code?

Comment: Hi Flavio, I know that, but I thought there would be a more elegant solution for this.

Comment: @FlavioOchoa The request includes an header. If you open the URL in a  new tab you have no control over the header value that is passed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stream the blob as file, you can use FileSaver.js at followed link:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Comment: brava bravissima Angela

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to download a CSV, here's a workaround I used and seems to be working just fine on Chrome and Safari. It's about downloading the data and then using a dummy `<a>` to trigger a download using an embedded `data:text` as URI. JS download credit goes to [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side).

```
ironAjax.addEventListener("response", (event) => {
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + event.detail.response;
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "filename.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
    document.body.removeChild(link);
});
```