# Unidentified developer warning when downloading CSV via window.open

Tags: javascript, macos, csv

I'm trying to export CSV data per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) using `window.open`.

```
window.open(
  "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,id,email\n1,a@a.com..."
)
```

The browser correctly opens the window, and automatically downloads the CSV.  When I try to open the file in Numbers on Mac, I get:

```
“download.csv” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
```

Is it possible to change the string I'm giving to window.open to prevent this error?