# Textbox to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am pretty new to programming in general, and I am having trouble getting started on little project I want to work on.

Basically I want to create a Javascript/HTML site where users can input a list of contacts (name and email address) into a text box.  The text box will use a delimiter to separate each name and address, then export it to a certain location (column and row) on an Excel spreadsheet.

I would really appreciate any help on this, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe this will require server-side code because of client-side sandboxing.

Comment: This isn't possible client side as the browser doesn't have access to the file system. To do something like this, you would need to set up a server which would receive the information from the text box and then that server would write that information to the excel file that is located on the server. You can set up a google forms page which will do similar functionality to what you want. In google forms every entry will be appended to a google sheets spreadsheet.

Comment: I believe he's talking about using a dynamic webpage form to generate a sort of "contacts list" that can be exported as a CSV, which I do believe is possible.

Answer (score 0):

[How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Refer to this Q for how to export a JS Object as a CSV.

As far as actually building out your Form for this project, I'll leave you to it as there are many ways to do so.

Personally I would suggest creating a form with a "name" and "email" column that you can add rows to, then loop through them when the CSV Export is called.

Check out JQuery, if you're looking into strong client-side scripting and HTML/DOM Manipulation, it will help you out a lot in the long run.