# Downloading xls but in same column

Tags: javascript, excel

The below code successfully downloads the xls file but the data are in the same column. how can I make it to the different column. The code seems working perfectly if I use csv but with xls it is not working like expected. I just want to make it like it appears on csv data.

Excel Data
[image: screenshot how it appears]

CSV Data
[image]

```
    var data = [
      ['name1', 'city1', 'some other info'],
      ['name2', 'city2', 'more info'],
      ['name2', 'city2', 'more info'],
      ['name2', 'city2', 'more info'],
      ['name2', 'city2', 'more info'],
      ['name2', 'city2', 'more info']
    ];

    var csvContent = '';
    data.forEach(function(infoArray, index) {
      dataString = infoArray.join(" ");
      csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + '\n' : dataString;
    });


    var download = function(content, fileName, mimeType) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream';

      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([content], {
          type: mimeType
        }), fileName);
      } else if (URL && 'download' in a) { 
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {
          type: mimeType
        }));
        a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      } else {
        location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(content); 
      }
    }

    download(csvContent, 'dowload.xls', 'text/xls;encoding:utf-8');
```

[credit link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a script that creates xls file with super easy. Requires some dependent file such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Blob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

All those locally saved file `blob.js` and `FileSaver.js` can be found in [here](http://view-source:http://sheetjs.com/demos/writexlsx.html)

Code

```
function datenum(v, date1904) {
    if(date1904) v+=1462;
    var epoch = Date.parse(v);
    return (epoch - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

function sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data, opts) {
    var ws = {};
    var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
    for(var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
        for(var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
            if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
            if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
            if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
            if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
            var cell = {v: data[R][C] };
            if(cell.v == null) continue;
            var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

            if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
            else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
            else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
            }
            else cell.t = 's';

            ws[cell_ref] = cell;
        }
    }
    if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    return ws;
}

/* original data */

var excelData = [[1,2,3],[true, false, null, "sheetjs"],["foo","bar",new Date("2014-02-19T14:30Z"), "0.3"], ["baz", null, "qux"]]

function createExcel(data) {

    var ws_name = "SheetJS";

    function Workbook() {
        if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
        this.SheetNames = [];
        this.Sheets = {};
    }

    var wb = new Workbook(), ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data);

    /* add worksheet to workbook */
    wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
    wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});

    function s2ab(s) {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
        return buf;
    }
    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), "test.xlsx")

}
```