# How to export Javascript array data to excel on the client side

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, export

I have been struggling with Javascript array data to put it in excel on the client side. I have read this,[How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

But that is for CSV. I want Excel.

Answer (score 3):

I got a good answer. It may help someone out there

```
function excelformat() {
        var result_table = [
            ["Day", "Month", "Year"],
            ["1", "January", "2016"],
            ["2", "February", "2016"],
            ["3", "March", "2016"],
            ["4", "April", "2016"],
        ];
        var lineArray = [];
        result_table.forEach(function(infoArray, index) {
            var line = infoArray.join(" \t");
            lineArray.push(index == 0 ? line : line);
        });
        var csvContent = lineArray.join("\r\n");
        var excel_file = document.createElement('a');
        excel_file.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvContent));
        excel_file.setAttribute('download', 'Visitor_History.xls');
        document.body.appendChild(excel_file);
        excel_file.click();
        document.body.removeChild(excel_file);
    }
```

Comment: that's not an excel file at all - it's still a CSV, with a `.xls` file extension

Comment: CSV comes with "," for rows and "\n" for new lines   then datatype for csv is text/csv;charset=utf-8.

Comment: my point is you claim this creates an XLS file, it does not, it creates a CSV file with `.xls` as the filename extension - this doesn't change the actual content from csv to the far more complex xls

Comment: How can I do that please? For instance bold some lines, draw border lines.

Comment: it's your answer, dude

Comment: OK, I will revisit