# MERGE column when export excel using javascript?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I can export excel but the problem is I can't merge the excel header column. I have attached an image you can check. this is what I want to export like this.

[image: this is what I want to export my excel using javascript]

**i want to export this table in excel.**

```
                    <table id="" class="uk-report-table table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="1">Date Range</th>
                                <th colspan="5">
                                    <h2>Last 30 Days</h2>
                                </th>
                                <th colspan="5">
                                    <h2>Previous 30 Days</h2>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>A</th>
                                <th>B</th>
                                <th>C</th>
                                <th>D</th>
                                <th>E</th>
                                <th>A2</th>
                                <th>B2</th>
                                <th>C2</th>
                                <th>D2</th>
                                <th>E2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I used this code to export it works fine. I need to merge the first column cells.
you can avoid this solution if is there any solution for that.

here is the reference link: [How to export Javascript array data to excel on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447647/how-to-export-javascript-array-data-to-excel-on-the-client-side)

```js
var lineArray = [];
result_table.forEach(function(infoArray, index) {
  var line = infoArray.join(" \t");
  lineArray.push(index == 0 ? line : line);
});
var csvContent = lineArray.join("\r\n");
var excel_file = document.createElement('a');
excel_file.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvContent));
excel_file.setAttribute('download', 'Visitor_History.xls');
document.body.appendChild(excel_file);
excel_file.click();
document.body.removeChild(excel_file);
```

Comment: I didn't find any solution so that asked . 
would you suggest any of the existing solutions?

Comment: Would you share your detailed code description ?

Comment: I sheared my table formate. I want this table export to excel. 

I have attached an example photo that I want to export.

you can suggest me any solution for that using javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using a javascript based excel library (e.g. [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com/)) to produce a true excel file.  You'll have a lot more options with it than faking it via a csv or html file with a bogus mime-type which is what your sample code is doing.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL4amurx/).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function exportFile(){
  var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById('sampletable'));
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'sample.xlsx');
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="sampletable" class="uk-report-table table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="1">Date Range</th>
                                <th colspan="5">
                                    <h2>Last 30 Days</h2>
                                </th>
                                <th colspan="5">
                                    <h2>Previous 30 Days</h2>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>A</th>
                                <th>B</th>
                                <th>C</th>
                                <th>D</th>
                                <th>E</th>
                                <th>A2</th>
                                <th>B2</th>
                                <th>C2</th>
                                <th>D2</th>
                                <th>E2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
<button onclick="return exportFile()">Export</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. yes, really it works. 
Maybe it is the most popular reliable package, right?

Comment: It's had over half a million downloads -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx.  So I'd say it's pretty popular.