# ember.js Need to see if I can write Ember model items to a file then download

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to ember (and stackOverflow) and have an issue that I am trying to work through. I have a model for a list of items that I am able to add into, update, and delete and everything on that end works fine. What I would like to do is to try and take the items in the model and write them into a formatted text file to download.

The model data is fine.
I know I can use this code to download a file from a url: `< a href="urlFile" download="filename">`

I just don't see any guides that can get me from the model to the download and I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions that could point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend FileSaver.js.
It's a really handy tool to download stuff, we're using it in our company in our ember application.
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Simply include it in your vendor folder and in the ember-cli-build.js

*ember-cli-build.js*

```
app.import('vendor/FileSaver.js');
```

*Project Structure*

```
/app
/build
.
.
.
/vendor
  FileSaver.js
```

Then you can call it from anywhere with

```
saveAs(new File([file], filename, additionalParameters))
```

and it will download the file.

For further documentation you can look at the github page.