# Download client-side generated CSV via browser save dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, csv, download, export-to-csv

So technically i want to generate a csv using json2csv library and upon generating it wanted to download a file with a browser save dialog box such as below :

```
var csv = json2csv({ data: tableData.data, fields: fields });
var data = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
// Next : I want to download a file using a browser file dialog (wherein) i could change the filename
// FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'filename.csv'); 
// with this (above) i could download the file however I want the dialog box to open
```

Basically the desired output is like a file downloaded from a server where the browser opens up a save file dialog box (name, path, extension.. etc)

Is this possible thru client-side only?

Solutions that I've tried : [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server?noredirect=1&lq=1) this also just downloads the file without opening the save file dialog

CSV Library : www.mircozeiss.com/json2csv

FileSaver.js : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: I believe that you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)