# how to save data in CSV using javascript in the following format?

Tags: javascript, csv

```
Symbol: AAPL,Company: ABC ,Price: 132.54 (nextline)
Symbol: SDF,Company: ZX Corp,Price: 132.54(nextline)
```

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
var data = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,name1,city1,some other infoname2,city2,more info"
```

```js
var data = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,name1,city1,some other infoname2,city2,more info";

var encodedUri = encodeURI(data);
```

```html
<a href="file" download="file.scv">Download</>
```

You should have the above data in the variable to convert it to CSV once you have the data in the variable you can do the following.

```
var encodedUri = encodeURI(data);
window.open(encodedUri);
```