# How to Download oj-table data to csv in oracle JET

Tags: oracle-jet

Does anyone know how to Download oj-table data to csv in oracle JET.
I have oj-table populated with data source. now i want to provide a button to download this data to csv.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: 
Just realized you might have been asking for an inbuilt method from OJET to download as csv - OJET doesn't have any. 
It only has a component for uploading files: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=filePicker&demo=basic

---

Is the datasource an observableArray? If yes, you can convert it to a normal array like this:

```
var a = ko.observableArray();
var normalArray = a();
```

Is the datasource an ojCollection? If yes, convert it to a normal array like this:

```
var a = new oj.Collection();
var normalArray = a.toJSON();
```

After that you can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966131/4887159).

Answer (score 0):

You can use oj-sample-export-data component.