# how to make excel put string in new row

Tags: javascript, excel, newline, export-to-csv

I have written some javascript code which will extract data from website
There is two columns one is for href and other for the anchor text

so the javascript will copy this links and link text to the clipboard!
if i put \t tab between two values excel will put the string in separate columns
`"values1 \t values2"` try it! and for number of rows

```
"valuse1 \t values2 \n
 rvalues1 \t rvalues2"
```

but excel put everything in same row in different column

Comment: Use `\r\n`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) might help you.

Comment: It does not help either!