# Datatable Export to excel

Tags: javascript, excel, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I'm exporting to `excel` my`datatable`
But I need to know how to add another `title` or how I could write in the next row, this is the result I expect:

[image]

Currently this is the result that I get, but I need to add text in the next row:

[image]

This is the `script` where I am filling the `title`

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    "scrollX": true,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [{
                        extend: 'excel',
                        className: 'btn-sm btn-flat',
                        titleAttr: 'Export in Excel',
                        text: 'Exportar a Excel',

                        filename: 'PLANILLA PRODUCCION',
                        title: 'Planilla Produccion' ,


                    }],
                                            dom: "<'row'<'col-md-3'l><'col-md-6 text-center'B><'col-md-3'f>>" +
                               "<'row'<'col-md-12'tr>>" +
                               "<'row'<'col-md-5'i><'col-md-7'p>>",
                drawCallback: function (settings) {
                    if (!$('.datatable').parent().hasClass('table-responsive')) {
                        $('.datatable').wrap("<div class='table-responsive'></div>");
                    }
                },

                    language: {

                        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"


               }
                });
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the following question where they convert array object of JavaScript to CSV file, where you have to just add line break for first line text and next line text and then again line space between second to third line where you have array data.

[[How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side][possible) answer]

> const rows = [["name1", "city1", "some other info"], ["name2", "city2", "more info"]];  let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"; rows.forEach(function(rowArray){ let row = rowArray.join(",");  csvContent += row + "\r\n"; });

Comment: Even though the above may be right, it has nothing to do with the question.