# Creating CVS file text format

Tags: javascript

I am creating a CSV file using JavaScript. I was unable to manage text format(like header text should be bold). Please help me if anyone has any idea around my requirement.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: CSV cannot contain any formatting of fonts etc. It is a data only file format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Comment: @Lab Lab, the referenced post does not handle the aspect of "including text format" with CSV, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to include text formats in a CSV file. If you want to include formatting information with the data for display in Excel (or am application compatible to some extent with Excel) an alternative may be to produce an XLSX file instead. There are libraries available to do this in Javascript. See, for example, https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

EDIT: I have just noticed that the freely available community edition of js-xlsx apparently does not support formatting. An alternative is the following library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs