# Downloading a SQL database as a CSV instead of select rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-app-maker

I used a function to download some selections from a Lists object as a CSV. I'd like to do the same for the entire datasource connected to the Lists object, but am unsure of how to scale this to work with, as an example, 100,000 rows. On the button to download the List data as a CSV I have:

```
var rows = widget.root.descendants.MainTableBody.children._values;
var csvdata = [];

csvdata.push([["Email"],["Last Login"],["Sku ID"],["Sku Name"],["Docs Added Recently"]]);

for (var i in rows) {
  var t = [];
  t.push(rows[i].children.EmailField.text);
  t.push(rows[i].children.LastLoginField.text);
  t.push(rows[i].children.SkuIdField.text);
  t.push(rows[i].children.SkuNameField.text);
  t.push(rows[i].children.DocsAddedField.text);
  csvdata.push(t);
}

console.log(csvdata);
exportToCsv("LMexport",csvdata);
```

The export function is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24922761/1422413).I basically need the `rows` var to cover the entire table, but that's a lot of data.

The schema of the datasource in question:

[image: schema]

and the calculation used:
[image: schema calculation]

Here's what the table looks like in the UI for reference:

[image: UI screenshot]

Comment: There's no `docsAdded` parameter here.  ``Select`` selects 5 parameters, but none of them is docsAdded.

Comment: DocsAdded is in `ActivityReport`, which gets joined in - I can see the data in the UI - I'll include a screenshot

Comment: To be joined in, it should be selected somewhere. https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-inner-join/ All I see is Email, skuId, SkuName from m (Licensees) and Email and lastLogin from l(Activity Report). Either I'm missing something or DocsAdded is added after sql query.

Comment: It's not added in anywhere else - I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. After doing that it pulled in the DocsAdded var from the ActivityReport table and I was able to ue it.

Answer (score 0):

- Records  retrieved from query are array of objects
- You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to convert them to csv

#### Snippet:

```
function exportCsv(){
 var query = app.models.Employees.newQuery();
 //query.filters.... use query used to populate the datasource
 var records = query.run(); //[{},{},{}...]
 var csv = records.reduce(function(str, rec){
  var email = rec.Email;
  var login = rec.LastLogin;
  var skuId = rec.SkuId;
  return str + '"' + [email,login,skuId].join('","') + '"\n'; // result: "email","login","skuId"\n
},'');
return csv;
}
```

Comment: The newQuery command doesn't seem to be available on the calculated datasource - I can use `query` but I'm not sure how to format it with no parameters to just get everything.

Comment: @Ian This is a server script. I don't think it's wise to attempt 100,000 rows client side.  You can however call the server script from client side using `google.script.run()`

Comment: sorry about that, my bad. I put it in the server scripts area but I get the error `Cannot find field DocsAdded in the table schema!`. The datasource is a calculated datasource and that field is in there as a number.

Comment: @Ian I guess you need to calculate the field again from the model through apps script.

Comment: I'm not seeing an option to recalculate the model?

Comment: @Ian I have no idea how DocsAdded is calculated. You need to replicate the logic(DocsAdded calculation logic) using apps script. Can you edit your question with screenshots of calculated datasource and the current script you're using? More details and showing your effort increases your chances of getting a solution

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify - the calculation is simple, it's just pulling the data from other source databases. I'll add in more info of the datasources.