# Chrome download csv not working with encode uri component

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to export a simple CSV from javascript. I found this solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/okcoker/a5L6oppy/) which seems pretty straight forward. However, when I try to download it in chrome it doesn't seem to work and merely makes the page re-render?

```
var test_array = [["name1", 2, 3], ["name2", 4, 5], ["name3", 6, 7], ["name4", 8, 9], ["name5", 10, 11]];
var fname = "IJGResults";

var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
$("#pressme").click(function(){
    test_array.forEach(function(infoArray, index){
        dataString = infoArray.join(",");
        csvContent += dataString+ "\n";
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    window.open(encodedUri);
});
```

[Similar Question with similar anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Comment: Try using the second method on the accepted answer,  the one using anchor element. If the data is too big you might need to put it in a blob first like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542499/560593)

Comment: @PatrickEvans tried that as well. no luck. just downloading the tiny bit of data too

Comment: @PatrickEvans try to fiddle and you'll see

Comment: What is the `#pressme`? Is it some element that can cause page navigation, like an anchor `<a>` or a form's submit button? If so you need to prevent the default action of that element

Comment: @PatrickEvans it's an input