# How do I export csv data consistently across browsers?

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I have an array of time sheet data that I want to export as a csv file. My current implementation works great in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Safari (I haven't tested other browsers).

## Here's an example of what I'm working with

```
rows = [
  ["Client", "Project", "User", "Duration (mins)", "Description", "Duration (hh:mm)"],
  ["foo", "foo_project", "foo bar", 30, "I did some stuff here", "0:30"],
  ["foo", "foo_project", "foo bar", 180, "And some more stuff during this one", "2:00"],
  ["bar", "bar_project", "foo bar", 9, "Only worked for nine minutes here", "0:09"]
]

data = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"

joinedRows = rows.map(row => row.join(','))

data = data + joinedRows.join("\n")

link = document.createElement("a")

link.setAttribute('href', data)

link.click()
```

Running this snippet in Chrome will give you a properly formatted csv file, **but in Firefox, it will all be one row**.

Is the way that I'm creating `data` the right way to do it?

```js
let el = document.getElementById('button')
el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rows = [
    ["Client", "Project", "User", "Duration (mins)", "Description", "Duration (hh:mm)"],
    ["foo", "foo_project", "foo bar", 30, "I did some stuff here", "0:30"],
    ["foo", "foo_project", "foo bar", 180, "And some more stuff during this one", "2:00"],
    ["bar", "bar_project", "foo bar", 9, "Only worked for nine minutes here", "0:09"]
  ]

  data = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"

  joinedRows = rows.map(row => row.join(','))

  data = data + joinedRows.join("\n")

  link = document.createElement("a")

  link.setAttribute('href', data)

  link.click()
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Click to download</button>
```

Comment: In cases like this it's better to use an established library that handles edge cases, and compatibility than inventing the wheels by yourself. I usually use [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv) to convert from and to CSV.

Comment: @OriDrori I'm hoping to not use a library for this, but I will definitely keep Papa Parse in my back pocket if I can't figure anything else out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Comment: @Triby It sure does! Thank you!