# I need to download a CSV file from my Phonegap app

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

The framework is Codeigniter.
I have an array by a response from ajax call which is converted to a CSV file and stored as  `CsvString = "data:application/csv," + encodeURIComponent(array_name);` method. Now I need to download this **CsvString**. 
I have checked File transfer plugin but it required a URL which is not applicable in my case. Is there any alternative way.
File Transfer plugin required URL which is not applicable in my case.

```
fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("download error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
```

I already generated the file by ajax call all I need to download it.

Comment: Why can't you make download csv from server side i mean codeigniter side?

Comment: As far as I understand Phnegap used a plugin called File Transfer to download files. I have checked the plugin and it required a URL parameter and in my case URL not required because the file already generated by AJAX call.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: It's working only in the browser, not in the PhoneGap app.