# sheetjs create corrupted file, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

It creates file but when try open file, it prints an error, online browser xlxs viewer cannot open it too.

```
wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

titles = ['title','second title'];
answers_list_ = ['answer', 'second answer'];

var ws_data = [
    titles,
    answers_list_
];
var ws_name = "SheetJS";
var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, ws_name);


$("#button-a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'out.xlsx');
});
```

Comment: Happened to me when I was writing js NaNs into the file.

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't make much sense to write to an excel file, it's better to use csv, it's very easy to write, you can use php and js quickly and easily, especially if you don't need to add some styles, the csv file is perfectly opened by all modern programmers for reading tables. For javascript you can check it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) for php you can find it [there](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp)

Comment: Now explain that to your client who explicitly wants an excel file because their clients want an excel file.