# Why does my JS API client return one file per line of output, instead of a single file?

Tags: javascript, csv

Here is my code:

```
function id(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/);
      resolve(parsedLines);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}

document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file != undefined) {
    id(file).then(id => {
      console.log(id)
      console.log(parsedLines)
      console.log(typeof id);

      var idInt = id.map(Number);

      var idFiltered = id.filter(function(v){return v!==''});

      console.log(idFiltered)

      idFiltered.forEach(idFiltered => {
        getRelease(idFiltered);
      });
    });
  }
});

function getRelease(idFiltered) {
  return fetch(`https://api.*******.com/releases/${idFiltered}`, {
    'User-Agent': '*******/0.1',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
      return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
    } else {
      const id = data.id;
      const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : [];
      const country = data.country || 'Unknown';
      const released = data.released_formatted || 'Unknown';
      const genres = data.genres || [];
      const styles = data.styles || [];
      const tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist.map(track => track.title) : [];

      console.log(idFiltered);
      console.log(artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist)

      const rows = [
        [idFiltered, artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist],

      ];

      const ROW_NAMES = ["Release ID", "artists", "country", "released", "genres", "styles", "tracklist"];

      console.log(rows);

      let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
      + ROW_NAMES + "\n" + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");

      console.log(csvContent);

      var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
      link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
      document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

      link.click();

    }
  });
}
```

When I `console.log(csvContent)` I am getting one line each time, and it is happening 5 times instead of once. I think that is the nub of the problem as I seem to be cycling through `let csvContent` 5 times instead of just once. Perhaps I should separate that out into its own function?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966131/11642582), which is very similar to my code, and probably where I got mine from. That seems to be exactly what I am trying to do, so IDK what the problem is.

> You can do this in native JavaScript. You'll have to parse your data into correct CSV format as so (assuming you are using an array of arrays for your data...

I tried separating out all the `csvContent` stuff into its own function `download_csv()` , and it runs fine, but no csv file comes down now and I'm not sure how to do that.

Then I tried doing

```
  idFiltered.forEach(idFiltered => {
    getRelease(idFiltered);
  });
  download_csv();
```

...but I got

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: download_csv is not defined

Any help please? TIA

Edit: `idFiltered.forEach` is running `getRelease` for each ID, isn't it? So surely I need to split off `let csvContent` and so on into its own function, as that part should only run once, right?

Edit2: I am trying to write some separate function to take care of the download independently, but I however I write it I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: rows is undefined"

Edit3: I've given up trying to write a separate function to take care of the download independently, as I can't seem to do it without leaving some undefined variable. I'm totally at a loss how to do this now.

Edit4: OK, I have managed to carve off the download function without adding any errors, though now I don't get a download at all. I am fairly sure the download function needs to be separated off in order not to occur once per line though. So now, I have the following, though it never actually runs:

```
function download(rows) {
  const ROW_NAMES = ["Release ID", "artists", "country", "released", "genres", "styles", "tracklist"];

  console.log(rows);

  let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
  + ROW_NAMES + "\n" + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");

  console.log(csvContent);

  var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

  link.click();
}
```

Comment: But where did you define the `download_csv()` function?

Comment: @Kokodoko - I tried writing it as a separate function, to contain all the `let csvContent...` stuff. I figured, since `idFiltered.forEach(idFiltered)...` is running that stuff once for every line, it needs to be in its own function, right? But I don't know what I am doing so I just put it back as it originally was.