# objects-to-csv TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, csv

"TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function"

I get this error when i want to generate a csv file and put some data in it.

```
const objectstocsv = require('objects-to-csv');

export default {
    data () {
        return {
        data : [
            {code: 'CA', name: 'California'},
            {code: 'TX', name: 'Texas'},
            {code: 'NY', name: 'New York'},
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {

        async exportData(){
            const csv = new objectstocsv(this.data);

            await csv.toDisk('./file.csv');

            console.log('ok')
            },

    }
}
```

Function is called when I click on a button. I don't get it

Comment: The question is incomplete. Currently it appears that you try to use Node-only lib in client-side app, which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The `fs` module depends on Node.js. It will not run in the browser.

Presumably, you have a webpack configuration that silently replaces it with an object that has a subset of browser-compatible features (which won't include any feature that actually touch the file system).

Either:

- Move your code that uses the `fs` module to a web service and access it using Ajax
- Replace your code that uses the `fs` module with code that will run in the browser (such as [this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146412/19068)).

The first step towards either of these would be to replace `toDisk` with `toString`.